# why the value cannot $_GET in the add-to-cart

Tags: php

Here is the page of food.php where it will link to order.php to add orders into cart.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row["foodID"];?>" />
            <dt>
            <img src="<?php echo  $row["food_img"];?>" />
            <input name="img"  type="hidden" class="img" value="<?php echo  $row["food_img"];?>" /> </dt>
            <dd>

         <form action="order.php" method="get" name="send" onSubmit="return Check()"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h3><?php echo  $row["food_name"];?>
                <input name="name"  type="hidden" class="name" value="<?php echo  $row["food_name"];?>" /></h3>
                <div class="detailtips">
                    <?php echo  $row["food_description"];?>
                </div>
                <p><span>Restaurant:</span><strong><?php echo  $row["restaurant_name"];?>
                <input name="restaurant"  type="hidden" class="restaurant" value="<?php echo  $row["restaurant_name"];?>" />
                </strong></p>
                <p><span>Type :</span><strong><?php echo  $row["food_type"];?></strong></p>

                <input name="num"  type="hidden" class="num" value="<?php echo  $row["order_num"];?>" />

                <p><span>Price :</span>RM &nbsp;<strong><?php echo  $row["food_price"];?>
                <input name="price"  type="hidden" class="price" value="<?php echo  $row["food_price"];?>" /></strong></p>

                <div class="order" style=" padding-top:20px; padding-left:20px;">
                <input name="" type="submit"  value="" class="ordersubmit" style=" margin-left:30px; margin-top:20px;">
                </div>
                </form>
```

Here is the order.php

```
<?php session_start();  
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE');
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
include("conn.php");

$action = $_GET['action'];
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
foreach ($_GET AS $key=>$value)
{
$key ;
}
$nameid=substr($key,4);
$namenum=$_GET[$key];
if($namenum){
    $arr = mysql_query("select * from  ordering  where id='$nameid'");
    $rowres = mysql_fetch_array($arr);
    $total=$rowres['food_price']*$namenum;
    $sqlup="update ordering SET  order_num='$namenum', total='$total' where id='$nameid'" ;
    $rus = mysql_query($sqlup);
  }
  if(empty($user)){
  echo "<script>alert('No login, please log in!');window.location='Log In.php';</script>";
  exit;
  }
  $orderID = $_GET['id'];
  $food_img = $_GET['img'];
  $food_name = $_GET['name'];
  $restaurant_name = $_GET['restaurant'];
  $food_price = $_GET['price'];
  $order_num = $_GET['num'];

  $total=$food_price*$order_num;
  if($action == 'add'){

   $arr = mysql_query("select * from  ordering  where id='$orderID'");
    $rowres = mysql_fetch_array($arr);

    $row=mysql_num_rows($arr);   
  if($row>0){$ordernum=$rowres['order_num']; 
      $t_price=$rowres['food_price'];
         $ordernum=$ordernum+$order_num;
                $t_pricea=$t_price*$ordernum;
            $sql="update ordering set order_num='$ordernum', total='$t_pricea' where id='$orderID' ";
             $resulta = mysql_query($sql);
                if($resulta==true)
  {
   echo "<script>alert('success');window.location.href='order.php'</script>";
  }
  }else{

    $sqlin="INSERT INTO ordering (`id`,`orderID`,`food_img`,`food_name`,`restaurant_name`,`food_price`,`total`,`order_num`,`username`,`time`)  VALUES('','$orderID','$food_img','$food_name','$restaurant_name','$food_price','$total','$order_num','$user',now()) ";
    $rus = mysql_query($sqlin);
       if($rus==true)
  {
   echo "<script>alert('success');window.location.href='order.php'</script>";
  }

      } 

  }

  ?>
  <?PHP 
  if($action=="delcar"){
  $delid=$_POST['delcar'];
  $pieces = explode(",", $delid); 
  if($pieces==""){
            echo "<script language=\"javascript\">alert('please choose!');window.location.href='order.php'</script>";die;

      }
   $arrayLen = sizeof( $pieces );
   for( $i = 0; $i< $arrayLen ;$i++ )
   {
   $sql="delete from  ordering where id='$pieces[$i]'";    

   $result=mysql_query($sql);  }
   if($result==true)
   {
   echo "<script language=\"javascript\">alert('del  success!');window.location.href='order.php'</script>";die;
   }else{
    echo "<script language=\"javascript\">alert('del  failed, please re-enter!');window.location.href='order.php'</script>";die;
   }    

   }
   ?>
```

Here is the form to link to orderlist.php

```
   <div class="shopbox">
    <form method="get" action="orderlist.php" id="shopcarall" >
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="change" />

 <div class="shopmain">

<ul><li style="padding:30px 10px 0 0"><input name="chackcar[]" type="checkbox"  class="userid"  value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" /></li>
      <li class="boxa"> <img src="<?php echo $row['food_img'];?>" width="130" height="98"> </li>
      <li class="boxb">
    <h3>Food name</h3>
    <h4><?php echo $row['food_name'];?> </h4>
  </li>
   <li class="boxc">
    <h3>Restaurant</h3>
    <h4> <?php echo $row['restaurant_name']; ?> </h4>
  </li>
      <li class="boxc">
    <h3>Food  price</h3>
    <h4> <?php echo $row['food_price']; ?> </h4>
  </li>
      <li class="boxc">
    <h3>Order  num</h3>

       <h4>

         <a class="del" href="javascript:void(0)"> - </a><input type="text" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="inputcss" value="<?php echo $row['order_num']; ?>" style=" margin:0; float:left">
        <a class="add" href="javascript:void(0)"> + </a>
        </h4>

  </li>
      <li class="boxc">
    <h3>Total</h3>
    <h4>RM <?php echo $row['total'];?></h4>
  </li>
    </ul>


            </div>
    </form>
```

Why the value in food.php I can't get in order.php?
Is that any wrong in my coding?
Since the name of input is matched with $_GET[''], I still don't know why the data is not showing?

Comment: Try removing header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");  from order.php. I think becouse you are sending headers your $_GET is cleared.

Comment: After removed, it still the same, cannot get any data from food.php

Comment: Does your url contain $_GET data?

Comment: my url get this :order.php?name=Smokehouse+Bacon+Cheese+Burger&restaurant=Morganfield%27s&num=0&price=28.90

Comment: it can get food_name, restaurant_name, order_num, food_price

Comment: Everything looks fine. Var_dump $_GET at the begginging of order.php and see what you are getting.

Comment: it shows the result at the top : array(4) { ["name"]=> string(30) "Smokehouse Bacon Cheese Burger" ["restaurant"]=> string(13) "Morganfield's" ["num"]=> string(1) "0" ["price"]=> string(5) "28.90" }

Comment: So you are actually getting the data in order.php. Maybe just assign $_GET to variable at the top of the file and use it instead of using $_GET?

Comment: What is your meaning? Means all $orderID=$_GET['id']; put after session_start(); ??

Comment: I think i misunderstood you ;/. You want to access $_GET data which is send to order.php in food.php?

Comment: yup, all the info already at food.php, I just can't get the data although i already put <form action='order.php' method='get'> in food.php

Comment: You send data using $_GET to order.php but you are not sending anything back to food.php and therefore you can't access it.

Comment: I thought just using $_GET method to obtaining the data at food.php. Then what should I do to send back to food.php to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
session_start();  
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE');
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
include("conn.php");
$foodID = $_GET['id'];
$arr = mysql_query("select * from foodmenu where foodID=$foodID");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($arr);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Tumy</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foodcart.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="headerwrapper">
<div id="header" class="container">
    <div class="logo"> <a href="homepage.php"><img src="image/LOGO.png" alt="logo" width="165" height="74"></a> </div>
    <nav>
        <ul id="navigations">
            <li><a href="homepage.php">HOME</a></li>
            <li> <a href="restaurant.php">RESTAURANT</a></li>
            <li><a href="rating.php">CUSTOMER FEEDBACK</a></li>
            <li><a href="userprofile.php">USER PROFILE</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li>
        </ul>

    <a href="order.php"><img src="image/cart.png" width="50" height="50"></a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="indexbox"> 
    <?php    

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foodmenu where foodID = '$foodID'"); 
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
             ?>
<div class="detailback">
    <a href="restaurant.php">Restaurant</a><span>&gt;</span><?php echo $row["restaurant_name"];?><span>&gt;</span>
    <button onClick="goBack()" style="background-color:#F00; border:solid;">Food Menu</button>
    <script> function goBack(){
            window.history.back();
    }</script>
</div> 
<div class="detail">
    <div class="detailtop">

        <dl>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row["foodID"];?>" />
            <dt>
            <img src="<?php echo  $row["food_img"];?>" />
            <input name="img"  type="hidden" class="img" value="<?php echo  $row["food_img"];?>" /> </dt>
            <dd>

         <form action="order.php" method="get" name="send" onSubmit="return Check()"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h3><?php echo  $row["food_name"];?>
                <input name="name"  type="hidden" class="name" value="<?php echo  $row["food_name"];?>" /></h3>
                <div class="detailtips">
                    <?php echo  $row["food_description"];?>
                </div>
                <p><span>Restaurant:</span><strong><?php echo  $row["restaurant_name"];?>
                <input name="restaurant"  type="hidden" class="restaurant" value="<?php echo  $row["restaurant_name"];?>" />
                </strong></p>
                <p><span>Type :</span><strong><?php echo  $row["food_type"];?></strong></p>

                <input name="num"  type="hidden" class="num" value="<?php echo  $row["order_num"];?>" />

                <p><span>Price :</span>RM &nbsp;<strong><?php echo  $row["food_price"];?>
                <input name="price"  type="hidden" class="price" value="<?php echo  $row["food_price"];?>" /></strong></p>

                <div class="order" style=" padding-top:20px; padding-left:20px;">
                <input name="" type="submit"  value="" class="ordersubmit" style=" margin-left:30px; margin-top:20px;">
                </div>
                </form>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <?php }?>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<div class="copyrightswrapper">
<div id="copyrights" class="container">

   <p>&copy; TUMY - All Rights Reserved.</p>

</div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And all you want is pass $_GET["id"] from order.php?

Comment: different food have different foodID, when click on submit button, it will link to order.php which come out with all $_GET information from food.php

Comment: And you already tested that order.php is receiving this data through $_GET

Comment: nope, the data cannot GET.....food.php is successfully get the data from database based on $foodID = $_GET['id']; and I put <form action='order.php' method='get' > at the bottom of html, to add the food order into cart, but I dun know why order.php cannot get the data from food.php